# How to select index of an element in an ArrayList and change one of it's properties?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to change a specific property of an element in my `ArrayList`, but I don't know how. I want to change the 'infected' property on one of my objects to true.

I've tried using the 'set' method on my ArrayList to set one of the properties in the element of my choosing to something else but for some reason, it doesn't work.

```
rectangles.set(5,infected=false); //I want to change the 'infected' property at element 5 to true.

public class RectangleL{
    int sX,sY;
    Color color;
    int speed;int height; int width;int velX=0;int velY=0;;
    public boolean infected=false;
//blah
```

Comment: `rectangles.get(5).infected = true;`

Comment: You don't need to `set`. You need to `get` the element at the specified index, and then modify it.

Comment: You should [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `get` the relevant object from the list, and then manipulate it directly:

```
rectangles.get(5).infected = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

i Analyse your problem. You have to fetch all the values of that index in one variable so that you can edit this. Use HashMap for this is best way.I hope below code helps you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class RectangleL {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> lstShap = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String,String> shape1 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String,String> shape2 = new HashMap<>();
        lstShap.clear();
        shape1.put("width","30");
        shape1.put("height","40");
        shape1.put("infected","false");
        lstShap.add(0,shape1);

        shape2.put("width","20");
        shape2.put("height","49");
        shape2.put("infected","false");
        lstShap.add(1,shape2);

        System.out.println(lstShap.toString());
        shape1=lstShap.get(1);
        System.out.println(shape1.toString());
        shape1.put("infected","true");
        lstShap.set(1,shape1);

        System.out.println(lstShap.toString());
    }
}
```

Output::

```
[{infected=false, width=30, height=40}, {infected=false, width=20, height=49}]
{infected=false, width=20, height=49}
[{infected=false, width=30, height=40}, {infected=true, width=20, height=49}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just see this :

```
public class Main {

    public static class RectangleL {
        int sX, sY;
        String color;
        int speed;
        int height;
        int width;
        int velX = 0;
        int velY = 0;;
        public boolean infected = false;

        public int getsX() {
            return sX;
        }

        public void setsX(int sX) {
            this.sX = sX;
        }

        public int getsY() {
            return sY;
        }

        public void setsY(int sY) {
            this.sY = sY;
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public int getSpeed() {
            return speed;
        }

        public void setSpeed(int speed) {
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        public int getVelX() {
            return velX;
        }

        public void setVelX(int velX) {
            this.velX = velX;
        }

        public int getVelY() {
            return velY;
        }

        public void setVelY(int velY) {
            this.velY = velY;
        }

        public boolean isInfected() {
            return infected;
        }

        public void setInfected(boolean infected) {
            this.infected = infected;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "RectangleL [sX=" + sX + ", sY=" + sY + ", color=" + color + ", speed=" + speed + ", height="
                    + height + ", width=" + width + ", velX=" + velX + ", velY=" + velY + ", infected=" + infected
                    + "]";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<RectangleL> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
        // Let say you created a object with infected false;
        RectangleL rectangleL = new RectangleL();
        rectangleL.setColor("Red");
        rectangles.add(0, rectangleL); 
        System.out.println(rectangles.toString()); // old value
        rectangles.get(0).infected = true; // replace by new value 
        System.out.println(rectangles.toString()); // new value
    }

}
```

Output :

```
[RectangleL [sX=0, sY=0, color=Red, speed=0, height=0, width=0, velX=0, velY=0, infected=false]]
[RectangleL [sX=0, sY=0, color=Red, speed=0, height=0, width=0, velX=0, velY=0, infected=true]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the object you want to change from the ArrayList. Remember that ArrayList is just a container of Objects. Once you get the required object you can handle it just as an object.
So it can be:

```
RectangleL rectangle = rectangles.get(5);   
rectangle.infected = true;
```

Apart from this, you are also advised to create a getter and setter method in your class and making the infected field private so that you have more control on how your field can be accessed and modified.

Best of luck